# common parameters in iphone

Tags: iphone, parameters

How can I define common parameters in iPhone to use everywhere in different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write and retrieve your parameters from a .plist file:

```
NSString *filePath = @"Parameters.plist";
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSString *value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"parameterName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add common definitions class file (e.g. `AppConstansts.h`), fill it with defines (e.g. `#define CELL_HEIGHT 44.0`) and add an import line (`#import "AppConstansts.h"`) in `<Your project name>_Prefix.pch` file that is usually located under "Other Sources" group in the project.

After doing it CELL_HEIGHT will be accessible from all your source files...